# heimdall libusb error -1

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-6, heimdall

I am trying to flash TWRP on Samsung Galaxy S6 that I inherited from someone else, there was already some custom software on it, but I am not sure what exactly. File transfer to a computer works fine. The computer I am using has ubuntu 16.04 installed and heimdall from the official repositories v1.4.1) and the following works fine on an S4 mini:

```
$ heimdall print-pit
Heimdall v1.4.1

Copyright (c) 2010-2014 Benjamin Dobell, Glass Echidna
http://www.glassechidna.com.au/

This software is provided free of charge. Copying and redistribution is
encouraged.

If you appreciate this software and you would like to support future
development please consider donating:
http://www.glassechidna.com.au/donate/

Initialising connection...
Detecting device...
libusb: error [_get_usbfs_fd] libusb couldn't open USB device /dev/bus/usb/001/018: Input/output error
ERROR: Failed to access device. libusb error: -1
```

Comment: Try to run heimdall as root. `sudo heimdall whatevercommands`

Comment: already tried, did not work. I just made it work by switching to LXDE, it was probably missing a library and I am not sure why it did work on the s4 mini

Comment: Good that you found a solution. Answer the question for others who may have the same problem in the future.

Comment: it just stopped working...  not sure why. I set up the permissions for adb to work without sudo some time ago, I have to recheck, maybe I have add some rules.

Comment: Does this command work? `sudo chmod o+w -R /dev/bus/usb/whatevernumber`. Also remove udev restrictions.

Comment: no, still the same error. If I use sudo, the error changes: ERROR: Failed to send handshake!ERROR: Protocol initialisation failed!

Comment: Same error(s) with heimdall v1.4.2?

Comment: just compiled and tried heimdall 1.4.2, same problem.

Comment: the problem must be on the side of the s6, I was just able to flash twrp. Heimdall works, but only for a moment after entering download mode. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem must have been on the side of the s6. I was able to run `heimdall print-pit` successfully, but only for a moment after entering download mode.